# Transferring flights at LAX from United to New Zealand Air

Tags: international-travel, tsa, lax

Will I have to go through TSA again when I land at LAX? I'm coming in on United and leaving on New Zealand Air. I will be leaving Montana on United; it’s all booked on one itinerary through United and I go to New Zealand Air at LAX. I was just wondering once I get to LAX and I have to go into the international part of the airport, are you required to go through security to get into the international part or can I bypass TSA?

Comment: What's the full itinerary? You're flying into and then out of LAX, but where are those flights coming from/going to? Whether or not you need to go through security again at LAX may depend on whether your flight into LAX was domestic or international.

Comment: And are the flights on the same ticket?

Comment: Question seems clear to me: Depends on how you want to get there. You'll most likely be arriving in Terminal 7 or 8 on United. There is an air-side by connection to the Tom Bradley International Terminal where New Zealand most likely will depart from (check your itinerary). However, it's walk only and a fairly long walk. If you want to take the shuttle bus you need to exit the secure area and go through TSA again.

Answer (score 1):

**No, you will not go through the TSA again at LAX.**

US airports make no distinction between *departing* domestic and international flights, since there is no passport control on departure.  You will go through TSA security in Montana, board your flight, then arrive on the "airside" (post-security) of LAX and simply walk to your connecting international flight to New Zealand.

*Note*: This applies as long as there's airside connectivity between your arrival and departure terminals.  This is the case for Terminals 7/8 (United) and TBIT at LAX, and more generally most through-ticketed connections on the same alliance at major airports, but this may not be true for all airlines at all airports.

Source: I had essentially the same transfer at LAX earlier this year (domestic-LAX-international on United).

Comment: Maybe a short clarification for other readers: Only Terminals 4 - 8 are connected airside to the international terminal. For terminals 1 - 3 (i think Delta uses them) you have to exit the terminal and go through security at the international terminal again.

Comment: @dunni Fair point, added a note. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that  it's walk-only and quite long from TBIT to 7 or 8.  It's about a mile from Terminal 8 and https://www.travelcodex.com/long-take-change-terminals-lax/ puts it as a half hour walk or so. If you want to take the bus, you need to exit out of security,